# select option using jquery not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Here i am trying to get values based on `#category` selection when i select a category men or women,following select option should show the relevant options.what i did satisfied my requirement but this code doesn't work in ie.it shows all the options of the `#subcategory` instead of showing the respective option to the `#category`.any help is thankful.

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JUGWU/8/
**NOTE : check this link in IE**

**HTML:**

```
<select id="category" name="category">
    <option>-select-</option>
    <option value="MEN" id="menu1">MEN</option>
    <option value="WOMEN" id="menu2">WOMEN</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select id="subcategory">
        <option></option>
    <option id="Clothing" value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
    <option id="Accessories" value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
    <option id="Footwear" value="Footwear">Footwear</option>
    <option id="Watches" value="Watches">Watches</option>
    <option id="Sunglasses" value="Sunglasses">Sunglasses</option>
    <option id="Bags" value="Bags">Bags</option>
    </select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#category").change(function() {
   var xyz = $("option:selected").attr("id");
     alert(xyz);
    $("#subcategory option").prop('disabled', true).hide();
   if(xyz == "menu1"){

        $("#Clothing,#Footwear").prop('disabled', false).show();

   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Which version of IE?  Which version of jQuery?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't treat <option> elements as an ordinary part of the DOM.  Support for attributes, even simple ones like disabled, is spotty at best.  Your best bet is going to be to re-populate the select based on your filter - you can keep the other versions in an invisible div somewhere outside your form elemement.

Comment: It seems to work in IE10 and IE11 
also Why are you using `.show()` in  `$("#Clothing,#Footwear").prop('disabled', false).show();`?
and infact `.hide()` in  `$("#subcategory option").prop('disabled', true).hide();`? are you trying to show just the suitable features and hiding the rest?

Comment: @SaurabhSharma yes iam trying to show suitable options.in my machine(lenovob560,os:windows 7 64bit) its not working in IE10.

Comment: @cimmanon jquery version 1.10.1 and ie10 and below

Comment: Would not you rather have a javascript object in your page with two select array and feed according to the selected value?

Answer (score 2):

I ran this code in my own page and it works fine. However, when I run it in your fiddle with by debugger, I'm getting an error in IE11 in the jQuery file "Access is denied" at this line:

```
// Support: IE>8
// If iframe document is assigned to "document" variable and if iframe has been reloaded,
// IE will throw "permission denied" error when accessing "document" variable, see jQuery #13936
if ( parent && parent.frameElement ) {
    parent.attachEvent( "onbeforeunload", function() {
        setDocument();
    });
}
```

Changing to jquery 1.9 in your fiddle works fine, as does running your code with jquery 1.10.1 in my own window. Looks like the issue is related to how it's embedded in jsfiddle and not your actual code.

After further discussion, it looks like you have another issue: IE isn't handling the display of `<option>` elements the way you want. Chrome hides them, and IE doesn't.

You can't control how IE or other browsers choose the handle the visible property of the  element. Therefore, I would suggest you either have 2 dropdowns, one for men's category and one for women's, and then hide/show the appropriate one when the main category changes. Another option is to dynamically populate the select with the items related to that department.

I will post an example of both of these a little later for you if you need it.

I have created a new version of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JUGWU/16/)

This one is creating a javascript array of options:

```
var subcategories = [
    { category: "menu1", name: "Clothing"}, 
    { category: "menu1", name: "Accessories"}, 
    { category: "menu1", name: "Footwear" }, 
    { category: "menu2", name: "Watches" }, 
    { category: "menu2", name: "Sunglasses"}, 
    { category: "menu2", name: "Bags"}
];
```

Then, every time the category dropdown changes, all `option`s are removed from the subcategory and then we iterate through the subcategory array and add all items that match the newly selected category ID to the subcategory:

```
$("#subcategory option").remove();
$.each(subcategories, function () {
        if (this.category == selectedCategory)
            $("#subcategory").append(
                $("<option />")
                    .val(this.name)
                    .text(this.name));
    });
```

The above code uses the jQuery $.each function, since you're passing in the subcategories array as the first parameter, the function specified in the second parameter executes in the context of each individual item. Therefore "this" is really a reference to `subcategories[0]`, then `subcategories[1]`, etc. You could implement this with a normal javascript for loop as well.

Comment: can you please elobrate the answers i am a new jquery user did not get what you said.thanks in advance

Comment: Sure thing. The version of the jQuery library that you're using (1.10.1 under "Frameworks and Extensions" on the top left) is not being loaded into IE correctly and therefore causing your script to never run. I believe this is due to the page being embedded into a frame within the jsFiddle site. You have two options: 1) Change your framework in that dropdown to jQuery 1.9.1, which will load correctly in IE and allow the script to work or 2) test the code with a real webpage and not embedded in jsFiddle.

Comment: i am testing in my local server,Still the same problem.when i use jquery 1.9.1 all options get displayed but they are inaccessible(disabled),that gives a very poor UI.what i need is not to be displayed

Comment: Updated my answer. I will post additional code later to address.